# How to issue Shopify API REST post using file_get_contents()?

Tags: php, post, shopify, shopify-api

I am building a web app that uses Shopify's API, and while I can easily issue GET requests to display product information using the `file_get_contents()` function in PHP, I'm not having any luck using it to issue POST requests to update the inventory quantity of a product from the webapp. I would prefer to use this method if it is possible instead of installing an additional library/extension to use cURL. Here's my code:

```
$postdata = http_build_query(
    array(
        'location_id' => $locationID,
        'inventory_item_id' => $itemID,
        'inventory_adjustment' => 99
    )
);
        
$opts = array('https' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" .
                     "Accept: application/json\r\n" .
                     "Content-Length: " . strlen($postdata) . "rn",
        'content' => $postdata
    )
);
        
$context  = stream_context_create($opts);
        
$result = file_get_contents('https://' . API_key() . ':' . API_password() . '@' . $store . '.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/inventory_levels/adjust.json', false, $context);
json_decode($result, true);
if ($result) {
    echo $result;
}   else {
    echo "post failed<br>";
}
```

And because I can get the product info via a GET request I know the API key, password, and URL structure are okay. Any help would be greatly appreciated (I suspect the error lies in the header section somewhere). The above code returns `false` each time.

Comment: I think when you want to update the data, you need to check `file_put_contents` [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_filesystem_file_put_contents.asp) instead of `file_get_contents`.